# New creative cloud libraries

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, creative-cloud

Has anybody started using the new library feature in Creative Cloud 2015?  It looks really good in terms of managing assets, styles and colour palettes between files.  I use photoshop for UI design and the art board feature has been a god send.  It does start seriously chugging when you have complex designs.  Ideally, I'd like to have one library of all assets/styles/colours used and split the designs into separate files.

From what I've seen of the new libraries feature so far is that you can't update styles globally like you can with the paragraph styles palette.  So once you attach a style from the library palette, it only takes it once but isn't linked so if I want to change the base style in the future, this won't be possible.  Anybody have any work arounds/thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to edit the 'master' library copy of an asset stored in a Creative Cloud Asset library.

1. Download the asset to your local machine
2. Edit the asset
3. Navigate to the asset in the Library
4. Select `Actions > Replace` and upload your local, updated file.
5. The library master file will be replaced with your new version.

Any document that has used the Library file as a `Linked object` will be updated to the use the new version (when the file is opened).

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creative-cloud-libraries-sync-share-assets.html
https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/sync-files.html

Comment: H Jackson, thanks for the quick answer.  That seems to work well for stu like image assets.  I'm wondering more about text styles and how they're handled.  Do you know how they work?  I can't find much about them on the internet so far